# Python - Why do I have to use if __name__ == '__main__' in my test file

Tags: python, unit-testing

I came across the `unittest` module and I'm a bit confused. I have a question on the following code in my file `test_number.py`:

```
import unittest
from module import number

class NamesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_number(self):
        verify = number(4)
        self.assertEqual(verify, True)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

(function `number` from `module.py` just verifies some properities of given number)

I want to ask about the  `if __name__ == '__main__'` part. I know this ensures that the testing will not take place if I import this module, but why do I have to add this `if` statement in my test file if I'm running this directly? Or, in other words, why do I have to add this line of code if I know that, when I'm going to use the `number()` function somewhere in the future, I won't be importing it from `test_number.py` as `test_number()` but rather directly from `module`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: *You* might not want to import the tests, but a *test runner* might. The last two lines allow you to run the test file directly if you want to, but it's more likely you'll use e.g. `python -m unittest` to import and run *all* test modules in a project.

Comment: @markwalker_ no, the OP knows what it does they're just now sure why they'd do it here.

Comment: It is also a safe habit to do so in every file/module, so you do not forget in other modules when it really matters.